# Adding Custom Post Types to Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Can you please let me know if there is any way to add your own Custom Post Type to Woocommerce and use that instead of using Woocommerce Product?

Thank

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding custom post type / post to Woocommerce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548188/adding-custom-post-type-post-to-woocommerce)

Answer (score 3):

You can register a Custom Post Type regardless of WooCommerce. WooCommerce creates a "product" one so you wouldn't need that, but perhaps you want to create an "event" CPT for use with WooCommerce you can do that.

[CPT Documenation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

If you are planning on replacing the "product" CPT registered by WC then I would begin to question why are you using WC anyways? I suggest you make any additional CPT's you need as an extention of what WC does. Also you should study **CPTs** and **[variations](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/product-variations/)**, two completely different options/possible solutions for whatever you're trying to build. Variations are part of WC that offer some great options, where as CPT's are native to WP and have a very extensive ability; with them you can use **[woocommerce hooks](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/)** to integrate with WC as needed.

Hope that helps, good luck!

Comment: because Rest API for WooCommerce is far better than WP. Especially when using meta data.