# Adding custom post type / post to Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, codex

I have a **personal theme "A"** and I want that it can also work without Woocommerce.
When **Woocommerce "WC"** plugin is added I would integrate A products with WC. I have a custom post type called "objects", how can I make "object" buyable throught WC?

*I've alredy seen this answer on StackOverflow [Adding Custom Post Types to Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190256/adding-custom-post-types-to-woocommerce)
Where the solution in the end gives a free (not anymore) plugin to resolve.*

*I'd prefer to do this thing on my own, without helps of plugin. I'm curious and a pre-package solution isn't what i'm looking for.*

Comment: "I'm curious and a pre-package solution isn't what i'm looking for." But you can learn a ton from looking at how a plugin is doing something. I've never heard of this plugin before but I'm dropping the $5 to see what is under the hood... and I don't even have an immediate use for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try a easy thing .. you want a custom post type to store your products and when WooCommerce is integrated the added products in your custom post type can work as woocommerce products ..

1. Check if woocommerce is installed ot not.
2. If not, then Create a custom post type as 'product' (similar to woocommerce).
3. Add the custom fields similar to Woocommerce and add the products under that. (Image added for the custom fields with Woocommerce)
4. Now, add the products under custom post type , and when woocommerce will be added it will face a issue the custom post type already exist .
5. So if in future you want to add woocommerce to your site disable you register_post_Type function and install the WooCommerce.
6. All the products created in Custom post type will be visible in Woocommerce products options also

To check whether woocommerce is active or not use this code

```
<?php
    if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {
      // code that requires WooCommerce
    } else {
      // you don't appear to have WooCommerce activated
    }
    ?>
```

[image]

Comment: getting away with the custom post type "product" is the issue the OP wants to raise I suppose... it's stated that the OP wants 'object' as custom post type..

Answer (score 15):

I have [created a simple tutorial](http://reigelgallarde.me/programming/how-to-add-custom-post-type-to-woocommerce/) as to adding it here would be too long.

To achieved your goal, your post type must have a price. That said, the custom field for price should have a meta key `_price`.

if you already have a meta key which is not `_price`, you can add a filter to `woocommerce_get_price` shown below.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','reigel_woocommerce_get_price',20,2);
function reigel_woocommerce_get_price($price,$post){
    if ($post->post->post_type === 'post') // change this to your post type
        $price = get_post_meta($post->id, "price", true); // assuming your price meta key is price
    return $price;
}
```

With this, you can now add any post in your post type to the cart. Do so like `http://localhost/wordpress/cart/?add-to-cart=1` where 1 is the ID of your post in your post type.

sample result image after visiting that link:

[image: reigelgallarde.me]

Now, you have to setup a form like below..

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input name="add-to-cart" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post->ID ?>" />
    <input name="quantity" type="number" value="1" min="1"  />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Add to cart" />
</form>
```

you need to have this to get "Add to Cart" button. The name of the inputs are required to be as is.

Comment: A+ @Reigel! I don't even have a use for this yet, but it is just really interesting. Thanks for posting it.

Comment: thanks @helgatheviking, there are websites that have catalogs but don't have the cart functionality... using WooCommerce and this idea, it will help them big time... this idea is their first step...

Comment: I can't for the life of me get this to work. I've used the ACF plugin to add the _price meta value, which I can see in the DB with that key, but going to cart?add_to_cart=56 just doesn't do anything. Anyone else able to give a real world example of this working with a CPT?

Comment: @SteveWeaverCrawford I'm also facing this.

Comment: This will not work on woocommerce version 2.7 and probably all the versions to come.. because woocommerce in 2.7 will check the post type if it's product...

Comment: @Reigel the way you've done in the tutorial its not working now. Is there are any other methods or something else? I really need to add CPT into woocommerce.

Comment: @Reigel I'm using 2.6.14 which is the latest one. So what can I do here? Is there any other way ?

Comment: @tanim I ended up changing how I approached it, but one big factor in it not working (even for products) was that I was using add_to_cart, not add-to-cart :/

Comment: @all I just felt I'd let you know guys. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43273286/wp-custom-post-type-cant-already-add-to-cart-in-woocommerce-3-0-above

Answer (score 3):

[I'm selling a plugin that would enable to use Custom Post Type as "product" of WooCommerce](http://reigelgallarde.me/doc/woocommerce-custom-post-type-manager/). I did a lot of work on that to make it compatible with WooCommerce 3.0

But here is the most important part.
You have to create your own data store, like this:

first create a class that extends to `WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT`. The idea is to overwrite the existing function of this class that check the post type. I found `read` and `get_product_type` that does the checking.

```
class WCCPT_Product_Data_Store_CPT extends WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT {

    /**
     * Method to read a product from the database.
     * @param WC_Product
     */

    public function read( &$product ) {

        $product->set_defaults();

        if ( ! $product->get_id() || ! ( $post_object = get_post( $product->get_id() ) ) || ! in_array( $post_object->post_type, array( 'birds', 'product' ) ) ) { // change birds with your post type
            throw new Exception( __( 'Invalid product.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }

        $id = $product->get_id();

        $product->set_props( array(
            'name'              => $post_object->post_title,
            'slug'              => $post_object->post_name,
            'date_created'      => 0 < $post_object->post_date_gmt ? wc_string_to_timestamp( $post_object->post_date_gmt ) : null,
            'date_modified'     => 0 < $post_object->post_modified_gmt ? wc_string_to_timestamp( $post_object->post_modified_gmt ) : null,
            'status'            => $post_object->post_status,
            'description'       => $post_object->post_content,
            'short_description' => $post_object->post_excerpt,
            'parent_id'         => $post_object->post_parent,
            'menu_order'        => $post_object->menu_order,
            'reviews_allowed'   => 'open' === $post_object->comment_status,
        ) );

        $this->read_attributes( $product );
        $this->read_downloads( $product );
        $this->read_visibility( $product );
        $this->read_product_data( $product );
        $this->read_extra_data( $product );
        $product->set_object_read( true );
    }

    /**
     * Get the product type based on product ID.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @param int $product_id
     * @return bool|string
     */
    public function get_product_type( $product_id ) {
        $post_type = get_post_type( $product_id );
        if ( 'product_variation' === $post_type ) {
            return 'variation';
        } elseif ( in_array( $post_type, array( 'birds', 'product' ) ) ) { // change birds with your post type
            $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_type' );
            return ! empty( $terms ) ? sanitize_title( current( $terms )->name ) : 'simple';
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

after that, add a filter to `woocommerce_data_stores` and use your class.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_data_stores', 'woocommerce_data_stores' );

function woocommerce_data_stores ( $stores ) {      
    $stores['product'] = 'WCCPT_Product_Data_Store_CPT';
    return $stores;
}
```

with that, you'll be able to add a post type of `birds` to cart. But will not actually be a success add to cart. Because there's no price, cart will reject it.

[image: WooCommerce Custom Post Type]

To solve that, you need another filter. Below is a simple way of adding the price.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_product_get_price( $price, $product ) {

    if ($product->get_id() == 815 ) {
        $price = 10;        
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Once that's done, you'll have success adding to cart.

[image: WooCommerce Custom Post Type]

Comment: I have e-mailed you on your website, but you never responded.

Comment: It generates a fatal error → "Fatal error: Class 'WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT' not found in"

Comment: I get the following error `Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Invalid data store.`. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. After spending days I figured out how it should work and its solution.

Here what I did

1. Keep price meta as `_price` for my custom post
2. Changed the `if` condition in class  `woocommerce/includes/class-wc-product-factory.php`'s function `get_product_class` like this:

   before

   ```
   if ( 'product' === $post_type){
   ```

   after

   ```
   if ( 'product' === $post_type || 'packages' === $post_type ){
   ```

It worked perfectly.

Now I want to change this product type using some filter method. Can anybody let me know about it:

```
if ( 'product' === $post_type || 'packages' === $post_type ){
```

Comment: This solution doesn't  work anymore. `if ( 'product' === $post_type){`  have been removed from 4.3.X.

Comment: Avoid changing woo-commerce core codes, instead attach to a function or a filter in your plugins

Comment: You should never overwrite core or plugin (which is not yours) code. It will gone after updating of this plugin