# WP custom post type cant already add to cart in woocommerce 3.0 above

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I can still add custom post type to cart in WooCommerce 2.6 just by adding a filter to 'woocommerce_product_class'

```
function wc_product_class( $class, $product_type, $post_type ) {

  if( 'my_custom_post_type_slug' == $post_type )
    $class = 'WC_Product_Simple';

  return $class;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_class', 'wc_product_class', 10, 3);

//This will echo the carti item id
echo WC()->cart->add_to_cart($custom_post_type_id, $quantity, null, null, array());
```

Unfortunately this doesn't already work on the latest version of WooCommerce. Would somebody please help me what is the solution for this issue? Any suggestions, comments, solutions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[I'm selling a plugin that would enable to use Custom Post Type as "product" of WooCommerce](http://reigelgallarde.me/doc/woocommerce-custom-post-type-manager/). I did a lot of work on that.

But this is the most important part.
You have to create your own data store, like this:

first create a class that extends to `WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT`. The idea is to overwrite the existing function of this class that check the post type. I found `read` and `get_product_type` that does the checking.

```
class WCCPT_Product_Data_Store_CPT extends WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT {

    /**
     * Method to read a product from the database.
     * @param WC_Product
     */

    public function read( &$product ) {

        $product->set_defaults();

        if ( ! $product->get_id() || ! ( $post_object = get_post( $product->get_id() ) ) || ! in_array( $post_object->post_type, array( 'birds', 'product' ) ) ) { // change birds with your post type
            throw new Exception( __( 'Invalid product.', 'woocommerce' ) );
        }

        $id = $product->get_id();

        $product->set_props( array(
            'name'              => $post_object->post_title,
            'slug'              => $post_object->post_name,
            'date_created'      => 0 < $post_object->post_date_gmt ? wc_string_to_timestamp( $post_object->post_date_gmt ) : null,
            'date_modified'     => 0 < $post_object->post_modified_gmt ? wc_string_to_timestamp( $post_object->post_modified_gmt ) : null,
            'status'            => $post_object->post_status,
            'description'       => $post_object->post_content,
            'short_description' => $post_object->post_excerpt,
            'parent_id'         => $post_object->post_parent,
            'menu_order'        => $post_object->menu_order,
            'reviews_allowed'   => 'open' === $post_object->comment_status,
        ) );

        $this->read_attributes( $product );
        $this->read_downloads( $product );
        $this->read_visibility( $product );
        $this->read_product_data( $product );
        $this->read_extra_data( $product );
        $product->set_object_read( true );
    }

    /**
     * Get the product type based on product ID.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @param int $product_id
     * @return bool|string
     */
    public function get_product_type( $product_id ) {
        $post_type = get_post_type( $product_id );
        if ( 'product_variation' === $post_type ) {
            return 'variation';
        } elseif ( in_array( $post_type, array( 'birds', 'product' ) ) ) { // change birds with your post type
            $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_type' );
            return ! empty( $terms ) ? sanitize_title( current( $terms )->name ) : 'simple';
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

after that, add a filter to `woocommerce_data_stores` and use your class.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_data_stores', 'woocommerce_data_stores' );

function woocommerce_data_stores ( $stores ) {      
    $stores['product'] = 'WCCPT_Product_Data_Store_CPT';
    return $stores;
}
```

with that, you'll be able to add a post type of `birds` to cart. But will not actually be a success add to cart. Because there's no price, cart will reject it.

[image: WooCommerce Custom Post Type]

To solve that, you need another filter. Below is a simple way of adding the price.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_product_get_price( $price, $product ) {

    if ($product->get_id() == 815 ) {
        $price = 10;        
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Once that's done, you'll have success adding to cart.

[image: WooCommerce Custom Post Type]

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help. And also I have reviewed your plugin and I'm impressed. Great work.

Comment: @solomonculaste You're welcome. Please mark this as the answer if you found this correct and helpful.

Comment: hey reigel , i did all of that , still the post doesnt get added

Comment: , i have woo coomerce 3.04 installed

Comment: depends on how you are adding it. I mean "doesn't get added" could mean a lot of things.

Comment: I am adding it by calling the following url http://yourwebsite/cart/?add-to-cart=%post_id% .. when i replace the post id with with product id , the product gets added , how ever , when i substitute it with a post id , which had an _price field , it doesn't get added , it just says empty cart ..i know this is a vague answer , but i new wp , and as such m still getting familiarised by it's routing , i dont even know how to debug this , siince i don't know when the url is leading , to which php file ?..and so can u help me out understand the flow ,,of how to add to cart

Comment: reigel i tried buying your plugin , it says out of stock, please help me yaa i min a soup ..!!

Comment: @AmanSatija with the default installation there shouldn't be `out of stock` problem.

Comment: getting error : `Fatal error: Class 'WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT' not found` while loading in custom plugin

Comment: ok fixed,i have added condition `if (class_exists('WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT') ) {` now getting error : `invalid data store`

Comment: location is `WOOCOMMERCE\INCLUDES\CLASS-WC-DATA-STORE.PHP ON LINE 92`

Comment: find full solutions while using in custom plugin https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/14212#issuecomment-351032651

Comment: @NirmalGoswami, that should work... but you can also add that class above this line `$stores['product'] = 'WCCPT_Product_Data_Store_CPT';` easily...
but still, the better way is to create a class file and require it..

Comment: Great, will this work for upcoming woocommerce versions?

Comment: @Reigel does the plugin work with Woocommerce 3.7? And do i still need to add the above code to get it to work? Thanks