# Dynamic cart item pricing not working on orders in WooCommerce 3.0+

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, price

I am using WooCommerce 3.0+ and I have set the product price on a certain page.

```
       $regular_price = get_post_meta( $_product->id, '_regular_price', true);
      $buyback_percentage = get_post_meta( $_product->id, '_goldpricelive_buy_back', true);
      $fixed_amount = get_post_meta( $_product->id, '_goldpricelive_fixed_amount', true);
      $markedup_price = get_post_meta( $_product->id, '_goldpricelive_markup', true);
      $buyback_price = ($regular_price - $fixed_amount)/(1 + $markedup_price/100)  * (1-$buyback_percentage/100);
      $_product->set_price($buyback_price);
```

The price is updating on my cart but when I click on to submit my order, Order object doesn't seem to get the price I set. It takes the origin product price.

Any idea on how I can accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: how are you calling all of these lines of codes?

Comment: i am calling it via the loop
$_product = wc_get_product($id)

Comment: well, `$_product->set_price($buyback_price);` will just set the price for this very moment of `$_product`. it will not save.

Comment: so is there any way that we can save it on that session only, i am trying to set the price dynamically without saving it to the database since i have a Buy and Sell section.

Comment: you should use the filter `woocommerce_product_get_price`. I have a sample usage here. Scroll down the bottom: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43273286/wp-custom-post-type-cant-already-add-to-cart-in-woocommerce-3-0-above/43539194?noredirect=1#comment74553760_43539194 But how you implement it is up to you.

Comment: this didnt work as i said it is not passing into the order object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated with `get_price()` method …**

You should use **`woocommerce_before_calculate_totals`** action hook setting inside this custom hooked function, your products IDs or an array of product IDs. 
Then for each of them you can make a custom calculation to set a custom price that will be set on Cart, checkout and after submitting in the order.

Here is that functional code tested on WooCommerce version 3.0+:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'adding_custom_price', 10, 1);
function adding_custom_price( $cart_obj ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Set below your targeted individual products IDs or arrays of product IDs
    $target_product_id = 53;
    $target_product_ids_arr = array(22, 56, 81);

    foreach ( $cart_obj->get_cart() as  $cart_item ) {
        // The corresponding product ID
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        // For a single product ID
        if($product_id == $target_product_id){
            // Custom calculation
            $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price() + 50;
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( floatval($price) );
        } 

        // For an array of product IDs 
        elseif( in_array( $product_id, $target_product_ids_arr ) ){
            // Custom calculation
            $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price() + 30;
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( floatval($price) );
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

> Then you can easily replace the fixed values in my fake calculations by your product dynamic values with that with get_post_meta() function just like in your code as you have the **`$product_id`** for each cart item…